# Swashbuckle doesn't detect my API endpoints

Tags: c#, swagger, umbraco, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a large Umbraco 10 application (running on .net core 6.0) and I'm trying to set up Swagger/Swashbuckle (using 6.5.0) to document a handful of APIs.

My controllers are in a separate library from the main Umbraco site, they work fine as API endpoints and look like this:

```
[Route("api/my-api-endpoint")]
[ApiController]
public class MyEndpointApiController: Controller {
  
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200Ok)]
    Public ActionResult Get() {
          return OK("This is working");
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I have this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // lots of other service configuration stuff
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "My Endpoint API",
                Version = "v1",
            });
            var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string[] xmlFilenames = new[] { "MyEndpoint.Api.xml", "MyLibrary.Models.xml" };

            options.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            foreach (var filename in xmlFilenames)
            {
                options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(basePath, filename));
            }
        });
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, TelemetryConfiguration telemetry)
    {

        // lots of other app configuration stuff.
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
    }
```

Everything builds and runs normally and I can access `/swagger/` but it has only documented the built-in Umbraco Forms API, there's no sign of `MyEndpointApiController` anywhere.

What do I need to do in order to tell Swashbuckle that it should be documenting my API endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem was that thanks to one of the other libraries installed in my application (Umbraco Forms in this case) I was in a situation where I had both [NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) installed in parallel which had confused Visual Studio's autocomplete offerings when I was looking for ways to use swagger, leaving me with a mish-mash of calls to different libraries.

To get access to `UseSwagger` from Swashbuckle I had to manually call the helper with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SwaggerBuilderExtensions.UseSwagger(app)` instead of being able to call `app.UseSwagger()` as the documentation suggests.